# could not initialize proxy [###] - no Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, proxy

I have coded with java, hibernate and spring. This error comes up when trying to add the `@Scheduled` annotation. Without Annotate using `@Scheduled` it works fine. what is the reason caused for this error?

Error as follows,

```
xyzLib: could not initialize proxy [ABC#8] - no Session
    at xyzService.customMethod(xyzService.java:1392) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
```

Hope someone can help me to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details you may need to add something like this above the method

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that we try to fetch a lazy-loaded object from the database by using a proxy object, but the Hibernate session is already closed.

I have fixed this error using `FetchType.EAGER` strategy.
I use this strategy along with a @OneToMany annotation, for example :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Set<Role> roles;
```

This is a sort of compromised answer for a precise utilization when we want to fetch the related series for most of our use cases.

So it is a lot simpler to declare the EAGER fetch kind as an alternative to explicitly fetching the series for most of the special enterprise flows.

more about this please refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-initialize-proxy-exception).